# requestAudioFocus fails after phone call hangs up due to AudioMode still being MODE_IN_CALL

Tags: android, telephonymanager, android-audiomanager

I have a music streaming application I'm working on.

Sometimes after a phone call interrupts the streaming I have the following issue:

My `phoneStateChangeListener()` gets called with `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE` as the passed in State.

I then call `AudioManager.requestAudioFocus()`, which fails.

I found this blog post:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/08/respecting-audio-focus.html

Which contains this line:

"Note: The system will not grant audio focus (AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_FAILED) if there is a phone call currently in process and the application will not receive AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN after the call ends."

Which pretty accurately sums up the behavior I'm seeing.  This struck me as odd so I added:

```
int mode = audioManager.getAudioMode()
if(audioMode == AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL) {
   Log.e("Trying to get Audio Focus","Mode IN call");
}
```

The logs show the following:

```
CALL SATETE WAS: 0
Trying to get Audio Focus(28009): Call State was IDLE
AUDIO MODE:(28009): Audio Mode was: 2
Trying to get Audio Focus(28009): Mode IN call
AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from demo.player.AudioFocusHelper$42a63068 hint:1
D/demo.player.MusicService(28009): FOCUS ATTEMPT FAILED
```

Which indicates to me that there is a delay between the switch to PHONE_STATE_IDLE and the AudioMode leaving Call Mode.

I have a work around for this which is to introduce a short delay before requesting AudioFocus (about .5seconds) and this appears to work.

I'm wondering though if there is a way to do this that wouldn't require a timer.

Edit:  This appears to only be a problem on some devices.  ON two S5's from different carriers (TMobile and Verizon) the Verizon carrier phone had this issue and the TMobile phone didn't.

Comment: Hey did you ever manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: Sorry but no, never resolved it